# Error al usar propiedades "private" en una clase creada con Lombok

Tags: java, spring, lombok

Estoy tratando de hacer un proyecto de tienda con Spring y encuentro  que si uso propiedades "private" en los modelos, da un error 500 al ejecutar el proyecto y tratar de ver una vista donde uso una lista de objetos del tipo de modelo que indico abajo.
En cambio, si uso las mismas propiedades como "public", el proyecto no da ningún error 500 al ejecutarlo y llamar a la misma vista que antes.

¿Alguien sabe a qué se puede deber esto?

Aquí dejo mi modelo:

```
package com.tienda.models.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="clientes")
public class Cliente {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;
    public String nombres;
    public String apellidos;
    public String telefono;
    public String email;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ciudades_id")
    public Ciudad ciudad;
    
}
```

Aquí el pom, por si fuera alguna dependencia:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.tienda</groupId>
    <artifactId>tienda</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>tienda</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.26</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Tambien encuentro que no me deja hacer import de "javax.persistence" y solo me da la opción de importar "jakarta.persistence..."
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Me parece que el problema pasa por otro lado. ¿Instalaste Lombok en el workspace de STS en el que estás trabajando? Me refiero a https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse

Comment: En respuesta a @GavilanPatagonico ya tenía Lombok instalado pero por algún motivo no debía estar funcionando correctamente. He vuelto a instalarlo en el workspace y ahora no da problemas con las propiedades "private". Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Agregué una respuesta y cambié el título de la publicación. Si la información del comentario y la respuesta te ayudaron a resolver el problema te pido que la marques como aceptada así otros usuarios que tengan el mismo problema (alguna vez lo tuve) y lleguen a esta pregunta sepan que esta es la forma de resolverlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este caso la clase se crea con la asistencia de la librería **Lombok**. La anotación `@Data`, entre otras cosas, genera **getters** que son públicos, por lo tanto el acceso a las propiedades de la clases es posible a través de sus **getters**, aunque estas propiedades sean privadas. Que no sea así indica un problema de funcionamiento de **Lombok**.

Cuando se usa **Lombok** desde Eclipse o cualquier proyecto relacionado (STS, JBDS, MyEclipse, etc) este debe ser instalado en cada IDE siguiendo el procedimiento que se explica [aquí](https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse).
Si, posteriormente a la instalación, se agregan nuevas versiones de estos IDEs, entonces **hay que ejecutar nuevamente el instalador de Lombok**.

Lo que hace el instalador de Lombok es copiarse a la carpeta del IDE y modificar el archivo de configuración .ini, agregando un *java agent* al lanzador de Eclipse.

Comment: Gracias, Gavilan. Respecto a que me haga los import desde "jakarta.persistence" en lugar de "javax.persistence", ¿sabes por qué puede ser? ¿Está en desuso "javax.persistence"? Gracias nuevamente.

Comment: Estás usando la nueva versión de Spring Boot, la 3. Migraron todas las Java EE api a sus equivalentes en Jakarta. Tal vez te convenga replantear el proyecto con la última versión disponible de Spring Boot 2 si querés seguir con javax por algún tiempo más. En el siguiente enlace podés leer más sobre la nueva versión de Spring Boot: https://spring.io/blog/2022/01/20/spring-boot-3-0-0-m1-is-now-available